# Как создаётся объект структуры без new?

Tags: c#

Я наткнулся на этот код, поясните, пожалуйста, что здесь происходит.

```
TimeSpan timeInBusiness = DateTime.Now - new DateTime(2018, 8, 14);
int a = Convert.ToInt32(timeInBusiness.TotalDays);
```

Почему мы не создаем объект timeInBusiness через new?

```
TimeSpan timeInBusiness = new TimeSpan();
```

И как результат записался в TotalDays, если мы предварительно не присвоили туда значение?

Comment: Объект тут создался в результате операции вычитания двух объектов (двух дат). Соответственно, поля у него уже заполнены в соответствии с результатом вычитания.

Comment: Если вы посмотрите на [исходный код](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/DateTime.cs#L1536) `Now`, то поймете, что это статичное свойство структуры `DateTime`, которое при вызове делает определенные расчеты и за вас инициализирует новый `DateTime` объект с нужными значениями. Аналогично происходит при вызове каких либо операторов (в вашем случае [вычитание](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/DateTime.cs#L1902C10-L1902C10)), создается новый объект `TimeSpan` и отдается вам.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Стало понятно.